# Drupal 6 sign-up booking, reservation system with payments

Tags: events, drupal, e-commerce, registration, payment

I have tried to find out the working solution for implementing simple **events booking system** in Drupal 6 (limited places, payment, signing up/buying few places for friends).
System does not have to be big but easy to customize events to reserve/book places for.

I was surprised there are no complete solutions.
Most of the time I was directed to use modules like:
**[Date](http://drupal.org/project/date), [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar), [Signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup), [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart), [Signup Integration for Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_signup).**

Has anybody of you tested it? Is it working and customizable or you would suggest other alternatives on the subject?

Will appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: small note: it's "Ubercart" not "Ubercraft"

Comment: @Lukasz: how did you finally solve the problem? I have to do something similar: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/seat-reservations-for-recurring-events-on-given-days, and I'm really interested how you did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for the [Conference Organizing Install Profile](http://drupal.org/project/cod), which isn't quite together for Drupal 6 yet, but should be in the next month, as [the maintainer is presenting on it in late June](http://drupalcampcolorado.org/sessions/using-conference-organizing-distribution-manage-your-events-drupal). Until then, most of the components are available as drop-in features with the [COD support](http://drupal.org/project/cod_support) module.

You might also be interested in [MERCI](http://drupal.org/project/merci), which is all about "equipment" reservations, though the equipment could easily be seats in an event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am really surprised there is no ready Drupal recepies for such a common tasks as reservations.

Comment: I was surprised as well. The best I could find was uc_hotel, but it is problematic as well.
I had to take some good ideas from uc_hotel, and develop my own module, which might be released to public in the near future (called uc_availability, and supposibly add calendar availability to any given ubercart product).

Comment: @Shushu: have you successfully developed your own module? I would really be interested, as I have to develop something similar: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/seat-reservations-for-recurring-events-on-given-days . Do you have any hints, suggestions - or even a semi-finished module or anything that can help? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Scott Reynen: I didn't really have success with MERCI when trying to use that for table/seat reservations for different events. Have you already tried it for similar purposes? I'm just going to try COD - I'm curious if it's suitable... I've tried Reservation module (http://drupal.org/project/reservation) which seemed to have been built for just for this purpose, but I could figure out how to create rows and seats, it seemed to be limited, or I just overlooked something. I would be really grateful (+150 points :) ) if you could help me (see the link in my previous comment).

Comment: @Sk8erPeter: nope, I didn't finish it properly, mainly since the business partnership wasn't successful and I had to move ahead to new things.
I will try to look for some "leftovers", but I don't believe I kept anything that worth playing with, sorry.